# ngModel is used within a form on Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

By clicking the `Register` button on my login page, I'm redirected to the following page.

Where it says the following error

And this is my `login.html`

```
<ion-content padding class="loginPage">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
    <img src="../../assets/icon/iconLoginPage.png" class="loginImage"/>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="loginButton">
      <ion-input placeholder="E-mail" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="loginButton">
      <ion-input placeholder="Senha" type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <button ion-button full color="royal" (click)="login(user)">Login</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <button ion-button full color="light" (click)="register()">Cadastrar</button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[image: Image error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says you need to have  name attribute on the elements.If ngForm is used, all the input fields which has **`[(ngModel)]=""`** must have an attribute **`name`** with a value.

```
 <ion-input placeholder="Senha" name="password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></ion-input>
```

Do the same for all the elements.

Comment: So I should not use the type, but rather the name?

Comment: both should be there

Comment: @MikeOtharan great mark if that helped! have a nice day